# Integrating Instantaneous Accelerations taken at discrete time intervals

Tags: quadcopter, accelerometer, simulator, integration

I am trying to integrate instantaneous linear and angular acceleration taken at discrete time intervals (1/100 seconds, 100hz). data is collected beforehand, and integration is done offline, I only have access to these measurements at these discretized intervals, I have been trying to integrate these accelerations to reconstruct the original trajectory (position .ie x, y, z coordinates), but even at 100hz(data logging rate) there is quite a bit of deviation from the original trajectory, I have been using SEMI-IMPLICIT Euler for doing the integration.

and so I was wondering if there is any way to improve the accuracy of the integrated trajectory WITHOUT going significantly higher than 100hz (logging rate)?

note:
measurements are noiseless (simulator ground truth data), 
logging rate has a std. deviation of 5 Hz

dataset consist of inst. angular accelerations, and inst. linear accelerations in body frame. i have access to initial orientation, velocity, position.

current code:

```
def integratePosition(initialPosition, initialOrientation, initialLinearVelocityBody, initialAngularVelocity,
                                    linearAccelerationsBody, angularAccelerations, frequency):
initialLinearVelocityEarth = transformToEarthFrame(initialLinearVelocityBody, eulerToQuaternion(*initialOrientation))
for a, alpha, f in zip(linearAccelerationsBody, angularAccelerations, frequency):
    initialAngularVelocity = integrateAngularVelocity(initialAngularVelocity, alpha, f)
    initialOrientation = integrateOrientation(initialOrientation, initialAngularVelocity, f)

    initialLinearVelocityEarth += transformToEarthFrame(a, eulerToQuaternion(*initialOrientation)) / f
    initialPosition = integratePosition(initialPosition, initialLinearVelocityEarth, f)

    yield initialPosition
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more details of the actual math begin used before anyone can give you a useful answer.

Comment: ''trying to integrate these accelerations to integrate the original trajectory'', is a bit obscure to me what do you want to do reconstruct the desired trajectory from the acceleration ? desired position, velocity and/or acceleration ?
Also are you doing online integration or off-line ?

Comment: offline integration, the dataset consist of instantaneous accelerations (linear acceleration in body frame, angular accelerations) dataset is collected before hand, i will update the question to include these details

Comment: i am trying to reconstruct the trajectory ( position in ie x, y, z coordinates)

Comment: @ryan0270 i will add them ASAP

Comment: Can you add whether there is or there is not some periodic noise in the data ? Is the simulation running at 100 Hz itself? Or is it running higher? You r not experiencing an aliasing issue and you have exact values for initial speed and position right? Is the simulation also running the same integration method? Even simple changes as integration methods may change the solution especially as time goes on (because it integrates the errors!).

Comment: this is the simulator I am using https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim, it's called AirSim, there is no periodic noise that I am aware of, simulator physics engine is running at 1000hz, and I am collecting data at (100hz with a standard deviation of 5 hz)